# Object#method and dynamic responders

Tags: ruby, method-missing

I have a Ruby object (an ActiveRecord object, specifically) named `User`.  It responds to methods like `find_by_id`, `find_by_auth_token`, etc.  However, these aren't methods that are defined via `def` or `define_method`.  Instead, they are dynamic methods that are handled via `method_missing`.

I'd like to obtain a reference to one of these methods via [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method), e.g.:

```
User.method(:find_by_auth_token)
```

It doesn't look like this works though.  The best solution I've come up with is:

```
proc { |token| User.find_by_auth_token(token) }
```

Is there any other way around using such a wrapper method as this?  Am I really unable to use `Object#method` for dynamic methods?

Comment: For anyone who stumbles on this in the future, these dynamic finder methods will be deprecated in Rails 4.0. I'd personally be cautious of adding additional functionality on top of them. https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest answer is "no"—the only way to guarantee *in general* that `Object#method(:foo)` will return an instance of `Method` is by defining a method named `foo` on the object.

The more complected answer is that you can coerce `Object#method(:foo)` into returning an instance of `Method` by overriding `Object#respond_to_missing?` s.t. it returns `true` when given `:foo`. For example:

```
class User
  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
    method_name.to_s.start_with?('find_by_')
  end
end

m = User.new.method(:find_by_hackish_means)
# => #<Method: User#find_by_hackish_means>
```

(It's up to you to ensure that the method is actually defined):

```
m.call
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `find_by_hackish_means' for #<User:0x123>
```

Comment: Here's a more in-depth blog post on the subject: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/28335346416/always-define-respond-to-missing-when-overriding

Comment: +1. So it's really Rails' fault it doesn't work. I've started to fix it in that regard, e.g. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6169

Comment: Alright, that makes sense.  And @Marc-AndréLafortune, you answered my question that I immediately had in response to this answer. :)  Thanks to you both!